# checking / unchecking hidden checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I try to do my own designed checkbox based on html input type="checkbox" but when I try to toogle checked property by

```
$('#' + elementId).prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('#' + elementId).prop('checked', true);
```

it doesn't work. checkbox input ignore it.

He is my example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/earlgraycz/8whv1vzu/7/

Do you have some advice how to solve this issue?

Comment: where is the difference between you examples?

Comment: `console.log($('#MyCheckbox').is(':hover'));`?? What are you trying to do?

Comment: try `$('#' + elementId).attr('checked', "checked");`

Comment: html checkbox value setting is retarded - its not "checked: true" but "checked: checked"

Comment: try `$('#MyCheckbox').is(':checked')`